# ASP.NET MVC Core DisplayFor not rendering correct type when enumerating polymorphic IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, polymorphism, kentico-kontent

I am have a view model which has a property

```
public IRichTextContent Body { get; set; }
```

This interface inherits `IEnumerable<IRichTextBlock>` and there are 3 interfaces that inherit `IRichTextBlock`: `IHtmlContent`, `IInlineImage` and `IInlineContentItem`. These are all part of the [Kentico Kontent Delivery .NET SDK](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-net). The normal recommended rendering approach for this property is:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(vm => vm.Body)
```

and everything works fine. For the `IInlineImage` and `IHtmlContent` types, with no display templates in the solution, ASP.NET MVC calls the `ToString()` method on them. If I place display templates for the types in the solution then these are picked up and used. The `IInlineContentItem` has a property of type object that can hold various actual types and ASP.NET MVC correctly resolves the right display template for this object, presumably due to the `IEnumerable<object>` implementation ([see the InlineContentItem](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-net/blob/master/Kentico.Kontent.Delivery.Abstractions/Models/RichText/Blocks/InlineContentItem.cs)). Happy days so far, the meta data template resolution pixie magic works.

In some scenarios I want to be able to use different display templates, so a single display template for the type will not work. As the model property is a collection of different types I can't do this as it stands. So I figured I would enumerate the `IEnumerable<IRichTextBlock>` and then call `DisplayFor()` on the types passing a template where required. Something like this:

```
@foreach (var block in Model.Body)
{
    @switch (block)
    {
        case Kentico.Kontent.Delivery.Abstractions.IInlineImage image:
            @Html.DisplayFor(vm => image, "AmpInlineImage")
            break;
        default:
            @Html.DisplayFor(vm => block)
            break;
    }
}
```

For the case where I specify the template this works fine, the correct type is sent to the template. However, the default switch case without a template now does not resolve either the underlying type `ToString()` or the display templates in my solution. Instead it seems the default ASP.NET MVC object template is used for the `IHtmlContent` and nothing is rendered for the `IInlineContentItem`.

What is the difference here between the case where ASP.NET MVC correctly resolves the underlying types when enumerating the collection itself and the case where I am doing this? People do not normally seem to have issues with a foreach over a collection, but I presume the issue here is the polymorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Your presumption is correct: based on the ASP.NET Core MVC source, the difference is the polymorphism, or specifically that template resolution does not handle inheritance of `interface` types. Here is an abridged summary of [the method that finds the template name from the type](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/TemplateRenderer.cs#L187):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTypeNames(ModelMetadata modelMetadata, Type fieldType)
        {
            // ...
            var fieldTypeInfo = fieldType.GetTypeInfo();

            if (typeof(IEnumerable<IFormFile>) != fieldType)
            {
                yield return fieldType.Name;
            }

            if (fieldType == typeof(string))
            {
                // ...
            }
            else if (!modelMetadata.IsComplexType)
            {
                // A complex type is defined as a Type without a
                // TypeConverter that can convert from string
            }
            else if (!fieldTypeInfo.IsInterface)
            {
               var type = fieldType;
                while (true)
                {
                    type = type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
                    if (type == null || type == typeof(object))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    yield return type.Name;
                }
            }

            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(fieldType))
            {
                if (typeof(IEnumerable<IFormFile>).IsAssignableFrom(fieldType))
                {
                    // ...
                }

                yield return "Collection";
            }
            else if (typeof(IFormFile) != fieldType && typeof(IFormFile).IsAssignableFrom(fieldType))
            {
                yield return nameof(IFormFile);
            }

            yield return "Object";
        }
```

Note how:

1. The runtime type name is returned except for one special scenario.
2. There is a condition when the type is **not** an `interface` that returns the type names in the hierarchy.
3. Nothing else until the end where `"Object"` is returned as a generic template name.

This occurs regardless of the Kentico Kontent Delivery .NET SDK, and you can test it by creating a model property using an `IEnumerable` of a simple `interface` and setting it to a `List` of objects of a type implementing an `interface` that inherits that `interface`. If you do the `foreach` and `@Html.DisplayFor` on each item, the generic [Object template](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultDisplayTemplates.cs#L188) is used.

In this case, you have some options:

- Always pass in a template name (even create an extension method to automatically pull it from the runtime type).
- Implement the `IRichTextBlock.cshtml` template.
- Implement the `Object.cshtml` template.

An example of  `IRichTextBlock.cshtml` is this:

```
@model Kentico.Kontent.Delivery.Abstractions.IRichTextBlock

@switch (Model)
{
  case Kentico.Kontent.Delivery.Abstractions.IInlineContentItem inlineContentItem:
    // Render inlineContentItem
    break;
  default:
    @Html.Raw(Model.ToString())
    break;
}
```

Comment: The code of the `TemplateRenderer` class _appears_ to be always returning the _runtime type_, however, upon testing it shows one significant difference. If you pass the whole `RichTextContent` object to the `DisplayFor` method, the `GetTypeNames` method will run multiple times. First, it will return the type of the collection object. Then, it will return runtime types of the particular objects in the collection. If you run `DisplayFor` in a `foreach` loop, then it returns the _declared type_, i.e. `IRichTextBlock`.